# how can I write code to disapprove users whose status are not yet approve to post

Tags: php, laravel

pls help me to fix this. I am trying to figure out how to avoid users who are not yet approve to post on my platform

**this is my code in controller**

```
// current authenticated user status
$userStatus = auth()->user()->status;

// if the current authenticated user status is not approved return false
if($userStatus != Constants::APPROVED){
    return back()->with('error_message', 'not approved');
}
```

**this is my constant files**

```
class  Constants{
    const  APPROVED = "approved";
    const  PENDING = "pending";
    const  REJECTED = "rejected";
```

**finally my migration**

```
$table->string('status')->default("Pending");
```

Comment: Please include what isn't working for you and what you have done to debug it.

Comment: i have done something like this            // current authenticated user status
            // $userStatus = auth()->user()->status;
            // if the current authenticated user status is not approved return false
            // if($userStatus != Constants::APPROVED){
            //     return back()->with('error_message', 'not approved');
            // }

Answer (score 1):

You wrote `$table->string('status')->default("Pending");` and ind your const vars you write it lowercase. that would be the problem. Please check if you also consider lower and uppercase when setting the status.

```
class  Constants{
    const  APPROVED = "approved";
    const  PENDING = "pending";
    const  REJECTED = "rejected";
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel have the authorization already figured out for you, what you need to do is create a [middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/middleware) file named (eg. Status)

```
 public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($request->user()->status !== 'APPROVED') {
            return back()->with('error_message', 'not approved'); // do something if the user is not approved
        }

        return $next($request); // else just continue
    }
```

in your route now add the middleware

```
Route::post('/post', [PostController::class, 'post'])->middleware(['approved']);
```

Comment: after i have done what you asked me to do the  error still persist

Comment: @Peter please include the error. We can't help you with your error, if we can't see your error.

Comment: What does the error say exactly??

Comment: @Nicklas It returned this           return back()->with('error_message', 'not approved')